# Cannot divide by zero error on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, division

Hello all I am using DB2! I have a query that calculates the MPG over a period of 30 days it is done by capturing the change in odometer as the numerator and the sum of fuel purchases as the denominator. However I have a particular unit that is causing me some grief! 
Apparently he has not purchased any fuel within the last 30 days and as a result he is causing my query to return an error

```
Division by zero was attempted. SQLState = 22012
```

I thought I could be clever and use `coalesce` but it an unsupported type.
here is the query the mpg!

```
ROUND(((SELECT MAX(ODOMETER)-MIN(ODOMETER) FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE READINGDATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS AND O.UNIT_ID = DEFAULT_PUNIT)/
(SELECT SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL) FROM FC_POS T2 WHERE T2.DRIVER_ID = DRIVER.DRIVER_ID AND POS_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS)),2) AS MPG_30DAYS
```

Rather than actually returning a field of 0 it is just blank, so is there a function similar to `coalesce` that will force a return value?

Thanks for your help!

[image: Carnell is the source of my heartache]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would mean that this evaluates to 0:

```
(SELECT SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL)
 FROM FC_POS T2
 WHERE T2.DRIVER_ID = DRIVER.DRIVER_ID AND POS_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS
)
```

My suggestion is to use `NULLIF()` in the statement:

```
(SELECT NULLIF(SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL), 0)
 FROM FC_POS T2
 WHERE T2.DRIVER_ID = DRIVER.DRIVER_ID AND POS_DATE >= CURRENT DATE - 30 DAYS
)
```

This will replace the `0` with `NULL`, which should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks bro I will choose this as answer in 7 minutes when itr lets me !!! haha thanks

Comment: saw you had a book on your bio, does it go into details about functions like this ?

Comment: @OliverH . . . It does, in fact, recommend the use of `nullif()` to prevent divide-by-zero errors.